# Magento2: Filtering the catalog by attribute does not accurately display configurable products

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, magento2.4, filter

Catalog filtering by attribute not shows accurately products who are configurable, when one variant of this products have value matched to filter value, in the catalog are showing all variants of this configurable product even this who don't have equal values to filter. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue of catalog filtering in Magento where all variants of a configurable product are displayed even when only one variant matches the filter value, you need to adjust the way Magento handles the filtering for configurable products. By default, Magento shows all variants if at least one variant matches the filter criteria. Here are steps to refine this behavior:

1. Custom Module: Develop a custom Magento module that overrides the default filtering behavior. This module will need to modify the way Magento aggregates and displays filterable attributes for configurable products.
2. Modify Product Collection: In your custom module, you'll need to adjust the product collection query. This involves changing the logic so that only those configurable products whose variants exactly match the filter criteria are displayed.
3. Focus on Child Products: Ensure that the filtering logic checks the attributes of the child products (variants) of the configurable product and not just the parent product.
4. Update Layered Navigation: Adjust the layered navigation logic to accurately count and display only the products that meet the filter criteria.
5. Testing: Thoroughly test the updated filtering functionality in a development or staging environment to ensure it works as expected and does not introduce any new issues.
6. Keep Performance in Mind: Be mindful of the potential performance impact of custom filtering logic, especially for stores with a large number of products or complex attributes.
7. Consider Extensions: Check if there are existing Magento extensions that address this issue. Sometimes, third-party extensions can provide a ready-made solution without the need for custom development.

Remember, custom development in Magento should be done by someone with expertise in Magento development to ensure compatibility and stability of your site. Additionally, keep Magento and any extensions up to date, as updates might include improvements or fixes related to product filtering.